# How can I find out what this Windows Firewall message is coming from?

Tags: windows-10, firewall

I get this Windows Firewall notification asking for firewall permission from time to time:

[image]

I am not sure what is asking for this firewall permission. Is there any way to find out what program is causing this? I don't have a 24836000... file in c:. I have different kinds of programs installed on this computer including webservers, but I don't have them running in the background all the time. Does windows defender keep a log of what program is requesting permissions, or is there any other way to find out?

OS: Windows 10 Home build: 19041.746

Comment: Do you have Windows Explorer set to show hidden and system files?

Comment: This does look like a malware to me, prepare for clean reinstall.

Comment: May be malware. Attempt a virus scan using a reputable tool such as Malwarebytes.

Comment: @spikey_richie yes

Comment: I have an antivirus with real time scan running at all times, and I keep Windows and the antivirus up to date so I want to hope this is not malware. I haven't seen any other weird behaviour and everything in task manager looks normal as well. I think I do remember seeing something similar to this a long time ago while installing drivers and software for a USB logic analyzer tool. It's was a cheap Chinese device so the fact that it showed weird numbers is probably due to bad design. I think this is probably something related to that, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Does windows defender keep a log of what program is requesting permissions?

Comment: Have you enabled Windows Defender Firewall logging? If yes, you could check dropped packets and successful connections in these logs in %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log.

Comment: @Sunny I don't think I have, unless they're enabled by default. I'll have a look when I can and update